# redirect after login and signout firebase auth

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to make a redirect when the google auth login is successful. But I cannot use Route inside another Route in my case, because I am using it in another component :

```
class Shop extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ...initialState, isLogged: false,
        }
    }
    authListener = null;
    componentDidMount() {
        this.authListener = auth.onAuthStateChanged(userAuth => {
            if (!userAuth) {
                return;
            }

            this.setState({
                currentUser: userAuth,
                isLogged: true,
            })
```

How possibly can I make the redirection after login and logout ?

Comment: There is too little information provided. If you are using react-route v6 then you can achieve this with navigate(), if you use older versions then you can achieve this with history.push, how you setup Routing is not clear here

Comment: navigate ?  can i use it in react j s?

Comment: they have replaced history api in new react-router - https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Comment: one question, i have all routes in index.js , is it possible changing the routes to appjs >

Comment: Try to host your app(if its opensource) on codesandbox and then I can have a look, with what you provided we can't do much